# Using trigger() to check a checkbox, how can I tell if it's checked or not without the checked="checked" being set?

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery 1.9.0, if I use `.trigger('click')` on a checkbox, the `checked` attribute does not get set. Is there any way else I can tell if a checkbox is checked then? Right now, I have to explicitly handle that click event and manually toggle the attribute. With jQuery supposedly simplifying JavaScript, this seems like a long way to go about it.

I used to not have to do this in 1.8.3, but in 1.9.0, setting the attribute doesn't update the display in the browser for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the property, not the attribute. the attribute isn't very useful.

```
$(checkbox).prop("checked") // true if it is checked, false otherwise
$(checkbox).prop("checked",true) // make it checked
$(checkbox).prop("checked",false) // make it NOT checked
```

Edit for comment:

There's a selector for that:

```
$(".mycheckboxes:checked")
```

Comment: How would I go about pulling all elements where that property is true?

Comment: Oh, so the :checked selector checks the property then. I was thinking it just checked the attribute. Thanks, kevin.